# How to do a complex filter with IN in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to do update for complex filter:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET MYFIELD='hello' 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TABLE1.ID 
  FROM TABLE1 
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE2.IDFIRST 
  INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE3.IDTABLE1 
  WHERE TABLE2.IDTABLE1 IS NULL 
  AND TABLE2.SOMEFIELD=0 
  AND TABLE3.OTHERFIELD IS NULL)
```

but it hangs.

This executes in one second

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID 
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE2.IDFIRST 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE3.IDTABLE1 
WHERE TABLE2.IDTABLE1 IS NULL 
AND TABLE2.SOMEFIELD=0 
AND TABLE3.OTHERFIELD IS NULL
```

And this also hangs:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT TABLE1.ID 
  FROM TABLE1 
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE2.IDFIRST 
  INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE1.ID=TABLE3.IDTABLE1 
  WHERE TABLE2.IDTABLE1 IS NULL 
  AND TABLE2.SOMEFIELD=0 
  AND TABLE3.OTHERFIELD IS NULL)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to rewrite the IN to an EXISTS condition

Comment: Does it really hang, or is it just very slow? That said, it would probably be better to rewrite this to `MERGE` or - as suggested by a_horse - to use `EXISTS`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can't wait more than 5 minutes :D

Comment: It's good to know for troubleshooting, because the difference between hanging and just being very slow is the difference between "Oh, it's the 'well-known' IN doesn't perform that great in Firebird", or "sounds like some transaction isolation issue with locked tables or no rec_version", or "could be some crash/hang bug".

Comment: Use EXECUTE BLOCK or PROCEDURE